# Building Project with Depedencies’ Tests: CMake FetchContent Conflicting Targets

Tags: testing, cmake

I have problems building a project with two external dependencies that define the same target.

My goal is to be able to compile the project’s tests along with the project’s dependencies
tests too. For that I was thinking of building the unit tests when compiling from source
with FetchContent. If you included `include(CTest)` any subsequent calls to add_test would
include that test so afterwards all the tests (project + dependencies’) can be run with
`ctest` on on the build dir (`ctest --test-dir build`):

```
$ ctest --test-dir build
Internal ctest changing into directory: /home/eulersson/cmake-fetchcontent-conflicting-targets/build
Test project /home/eulersson/cmake-fetchcontent-conflicting-targets/build
(FIRST IT RUNS THE TESTS FROM THIS PROJECT (TEST_FOO))
      Start  1: test-foo
 1/62 Test  #1: test-foo ..........................   Passed    0.02 sec
 (NOW IT WOULD RUN THE TESTS FROM CJSON (DEPENDENCY))
      Start  2: cJSON_test
 2/62 Test  #2: cJSON_test ........................   Passed    0.02 sec
      Start  3: parse_examples
[...]
 (NOW IT WOULD RUN THE TESTS FROM LIBZMQ (DEPENDENCY))
[...]
```

Does this make sense? Perhaps there’s another way that conform to best practices?

When adding various dependencies into a CMake project, if you want to also build the
unit tests along them, I run into this problem where the target (in this case the unit
testing library “unity”) is being added twice by the various dependencies you want to
build tests for (add_library(unity STATIC [...])):

- add_library(unity [...]) in libzmq: https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/959a133520dfc80d29e83aa7ef762e1d0327f63b/tests/CMakeLists.txt#L206-L209
- add_library(unity [...]) in cJSON: https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON/blob/19ff92da79ee37c81a4cdf1f50a8dd1cbb02e84f/tests/CMakeLists.txt#L2

Reproducible exampe: https://github.com/eulersson/cmake-fetchcontent-conflicting-targets: Problem illustrating using FetchContent on projects defining the same un-namespaced target.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eulersson/cmake-fetchcontent-conflicting-targets
$ cd cmake-conflicting-targets
$ cmake -S . -B build
[...]
CMake Error at build/_deps/cjson-src/tests/CMakeLists.txt:2 (add_library):
  add_library cannot create target "unity" because another target with the
  same name already exists.  The existing target is a static library created
  in source directory
  "/Users/ramon/Devel/conflicting-targets/build/_deps/libzmq-src/tests".  See
  documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
```

This would not be an issue if those targets were namespaced.

What would be a good workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use FetchContent in your situation. When you have multiple dependencies that want to define the same target name, they clash, as you've observed. In such cases, you can't bring the dependencies directly into your main project, but you can build them with [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) since it creates its own separate sub-build.

In your scenario, you probably should use a superbuild based on ExternalProject. In the strictest sense, that means your main project is essentially nothing more than a bunch of `ExternalProject_Add()` calls. You must set up the dependencies between each of those calls to correctly express which ones depends on which others. If they are all CMake-based dependencies, you can set the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` of each one to point at the location(s) the other `ExternalProject_Add()` calls install to. Some people choose to use a single, common install area for all of them to keep things simple. Others choose to install each one to its own separate install area. You can find a reasonable discussion of the superbuild pattern in Kitware's [CMake Superbuilds and Git Submodules](https://www.kitware.com/cmake-superbuilds-git-submodules/) blog post, although it lacks examples.

Ultimately, what you probably want is the [project-level namespaces](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22687) feature I proposed in the CMake issue tracker. To my knowledge, no-one is working on it yet though, and I don't expect to have the time to dedicate to it myself in the medium term. It would be a pretty big task.

Comment: Not a big fan of FetchContent on my end. I like to use `find_package` in the main project, and if necessary build the dependencies on the side. It also feels closer to the "system package manager" experience. I elaborated about [handling dependencies with CMake](https://www.acarg.ch/posts/cmake-deps/) in a blog post, and also wrote about [CMake superbuilds](https://www.acarg.ch/posts/cmake-superbuild/) (spoiler: I think handling the dependencies manually is better). I would love to have your opinion :-).